# How to Receive Http-request in a ruby program

Tags: ruby

I know several gems for example net or faraday that can make http-request. But is there something to recieve Http-requests in a ruby program? Thanks

Comment: Might want to take a look at: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/web_servers, What is your use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To receive a HTTP request you need a way to listen for HTTP requests on some port - HTTP server.

You can write your own, or chose one from [many that are already available](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/web_servers), or you can use [WEBrick](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/WEBrick.html) which is included in Ruby standard library.

To give you an idea, here is a simple example of using WEBrick:

```
require 'webrick'

server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port => 8000)

class MyServlet < WEBrick::HTTPServlet::AbstractServlet
  def do_GET(request, response)
    response.body = "You requested '#{request.path}'"
  end
end

server.mount('', MyServlet)
trap('INT') {server.shutdown} # so you can stop the server using Ctrl-C
server.start
```

Then you can make some requests:

```
curl localhost:8000           # => You requested '/'
curl localhost:8000/something # => You requested '/something'
```